# Wordpress shows only one post

Tags: php, wordpress

I create the new Post and he exist but it doesnt show up. Any ideas? My version of PHP: 7.2.9

```
 <?php 

 if(have_posts()){

 while(have_posts()){ 
 the_post();
 }} ?>
 <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h1>
 <p><?php the_content() ?></p>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see quite some errors, the ';' is not something you can juste ommit in code and you just have none if that's really what you are running in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Everything now working well.

```
 <?php 

 while(have_posts()){ 
 the_post(); 
 ?> 
 <h1><a href ="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
 <p><?php the_content();?></p>
 <?php 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Still missing one in permalink